# Consuming Web Service Android 4.0

Tags: android, glassfish

Folks, I have an web service running on my PC, recently I changed my application from 2.2. for 4.0, and after that I cant connect to my WS anymore.

I'm looking for answers and found nothing.

My application refers the URL like this  `http://10.0.2.2:8080` ... But it dosn't work.

Heres my code:

```
private static final String URL_WS = "[this is not a link]http://10.0.2.2:8080/WS_TaxiShare/)";


public String login(String email, String password) throws Exception {

    String[] resposta = new WSClient().get(URL_WS + "login/login/?login="+ email +"&password="+ password);

    String saida = resposta[1];
    if (resposta[0].equals("200")) {
        return saida;
    } else {
        return saida;
    }
}
```

Now the WSClient

```
public class WSClient {

public final String[] get(String url) {

    String[] result = new String[2];
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        Log.i("Get taxi", "Url -> " + url);
        response = HttpClientSingleton.getHttpClientInstace().execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            result[0] = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result[1] = toString(instream);
            instream.close();
            Log.i("get", "Result from post JsonPost : " + result[0] + " : " + result[1]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Exception no get WS taxi", "Exception ->" + e);
        result[0] = "0";
        result[1] = "Falha de rede!";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Someone can help me?

PS: My WS running on Glassfish

Comment: I tried back the app to 2.2 and it works fine, but still not working in 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i can solve my problem. Android 4.0 (I dont know when it begin), you cant call webservices on the main thread. And all you need to do is create a async method to do what you need in a separeated thread.

Here is my method

```
private class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";


        try {
            //Pegando o email e a senha da tela
            String login = loginLogin.getText().toString();
            String password = loginSenha.getText().toString();

            WSTaxiShare ws = new WSTaxiShare();

            Log.i("inciando login taxi", "Login -> " + login + " Senha -> " + password);
            response = ws.login(login, password);
            Log.i("String resposta taxi", response + "");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception Login taxi", e + "");
            gerarToast("Não Foi possível logar");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {

        try {
            ...
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            ...
        }

    }


}
```

And here is the call button:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            loginTask task = new loginTask();
            task.execute(new String[] { "" });

        }
    });
```